# Site model is still using the old pre-version 2.0.0 model

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I wrote a plugin to create pdfs and that like in phase `site`.
Now among other problems, the following messages comes up when creating the site:

```
Site model of 'eu.simuline.m2latex:latex-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-SNAPSHOT' 
for locale 'en' is still using the old pre-version 2.0.0 model. 
You MUST migrate to the new model as soon as possible 
otherwise your build will break in the future!
```

This does not occur if `maven-site-plugin` is in version `4.0.0-M8`
but it does occur in all versions M9 up to the currently newest M11.
As `doxia-module-markdown` I use the currently newest, `2.0.0-M8`.
In `site.xml` I use `maven-fluido-skin`, version `2.0.0-M6`.

I cannot figure out what a site model is...
and I dont know what happened in the transition M8 to M9.

Comment: First a link to a github repos would be helpful? Furthermore check https://maven.apache.org/doxia/doxia-sitetools/doxia-site-model/site.html ? Also why not using Asciidoctor or alike to create PDF's ?

Comment: Well, I have some requirements on the documents, so I prefer latex. 
And I did not find a reasonable plugin,.. well i did find.. and developed further.

Comment: @khmarbaise: I pushed the pom and the site.xml to the github repo `https://github.com/Reissner/latex-maven-plugin`.

Comment: @khmarbaise: your link confuses me. From the documentation of the site plugin one reaches `https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/sitedescriptor.html`. There the link to reference documentation for the site descriptor  resembles site.xml as you describe it with root element site, but I use with root element project. Is this the difference???

Comment: First I would make a bet on it ... maybe there are other things but first start with that... also check the name space in the document... etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise: ok, you were right, your hint solved the problem. 
Still I notified the developers of the site plugin, that the documentation shall clearly state the change of the model and also provide sites for the schema links.

Comment: @khmarbaise: If you sent an answer, I can mark as accepted and upvote.